# Java - ArrayList of Modules - how do I

Tags: java

list all modules in the ArraryList? -

I thought it'd be something like below but this won't compile (error - cannot find symbol - method list).

```
/**
 * This method lists all modules in the ArrayList
 */
public String listAllModules()
{
    return modules.list();
}
```

Thanks.  (new to Java in case that isn't obvious..)

Comment: Do you mean you want a list of all the entries in the list? If that's the case you can just use the `toString` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a String List of your List Elements you can override the toString Method to fit your needs.

and then like

```
public String listAllModules()
{
    return modules.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method list() isn't available for ArrayList. Use a for loop instead:

```
for (Module m: modules) {
   System.out.println(m);
}
```

Assuming that the ArrayList modules has objects with the type of Module

Comment: Thanks Roflcoptr - what class could i import that has a method list()?  L

Comment: It depends what you want to do in your list method. Afaik the colleciton types in java don't have any list method. But you can implement it by yourself. What should your list method do?

Comment: i just want to list all modules in an arraylist - my java knowledge is basic so far and i'm working through some past exam papers, i;m trying to keep it as simple (and easy to remember as possible) in case something similar comes up again...

Comment: Yes then you can use the code snipplet from above. Maybe you want to use System.out.println(m.toString()); instead System.out.println(m), depending on what exactly should be listed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to iterate through a List?  Try this:

```
for (Object o : modules) {
    // do something with each object from the list
}
```

Hard to understand what you're trying to do without more information.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick responses - as a matter of interest is there a class that i could import that would make what i wrote initally valid?  i.e. one that contains a list method?  L

Comment: Afair, now there isn't a collection type that has a list method.

Comment: thanks again for the quick responses, that's cleared the confusion up for me.  L

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you have, you might want to try out the [toString()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29) method. If you want something more customizable, you can do something like this:

```
public String listAllModules()
{
   StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < modules.size(); i++)
   {
     str.append(modules.get(i));  // you can append any other data here
   }

   return str.toString();
}
```

You can take a look at the [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) api or more information. In the above code, I am assuming that ArrayList modules is an arraylist of strings, ie: ArrayList modules.

Answer (score -1):

I am unclear about the type of 'modules' variable.  If it is array then you can simply use, Arrays.asList(modules);